# I've generated a public key: 2976 bits ...?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, public-key

I have generated a public key via `ssh-keygen -f foo`. The key inside the file `foo.pub` is `AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDaJ1UGxfjTCzuVNvgjOyK/NF5KFDO2qUREGd9PBB+zJotS85XO9hQjq5XhdekXHfhCM/h3AeGW/xH+XfQIaNd6Lygkts3xls7FCqMVH4PxDpLTSQbbZCV+peMV6xNVv468SD07TGIp9RC0FFuR79tnz28X9RzKCUGrzpu38pAyPs4X3BGgMsc6IcPIfPnEZ61RMWiiouyShKuhD/G68DeTdokmmK0EnO2qMXgu7xsAw+2gSpotIgAPulAPpQr5+Cgit94GpN2Vy9OvhEGT3oqHsR8P4zoJ3rWppiCUDRvFZS/fQsRoNj59LRcPRVE0V8wLnpoEZOu85wBMiIfiac3F`. That is 372 characters. 1 character is 8 bits, thus my key is a 372 * 8 = 2976 bit key. That cannot be true because `man ssh-keygen` says that the default is 2048 bits. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The .pub file contains a base64 encoded version of your key as well as some additional information, which leads to seemingly more than 2048 bits, due to the encoding overhead.

Comment: oh okay I understand, it makes sense. If I had a sequence of 1's and 0's there could be an 8-bit sequence which doesn't refer to a readable ascii char, right? But since the key is supposed to be printed into a file there must be some sort of conversion which is "base64". I'll read more about it, thanks already for pointing me in the right direction!